# JavaScript: variable within an object is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems when trying to store a 2D-array in an object variable.

```
var prTClass = {
    prT: Create2DArray(5,8),
    setPriceT: function(i,j,price){
        prT[i][j] = price;
    },
    ...
}
```

Create2DArray() is not throwing any error, and the code is this:

```
function Create2DArray(rows,columns) {
    var mat = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        mat[x] = [];    
        for(var y = 0; y < columns; y++){ 
            mat[x][y] = 'X';    
        }    
    }
    return mat;
}
```

The message error I'm getting is **"Uncaught ReferenceError: prT is not defined"**.
I also tried to instantiate the variable with an init() function, like this:

```
prT: [],
init: function(){
    this.prT=Create2DArray(5,8);
},
```

What's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: In order for `this` in `init` to refer to the object that holds `prT`, you need to invoke `init` in a way that properly sets its `this` value. Since you're not showing how `init` is invoked, I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: You are creating an object.  I think you should define a class for the object and then instantiate it.

Comment: Or is your issue coming from the `setPriceT` method? If so, it's becauase `prt` is not a variable. It's an object property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lacking `this`. You can never access `prT` as just `prT`. You must always access it as either `this.prT` from within the context of that object, or `prTClass.prT` from outside.